# Trying to create a dictionary of clothes available in store in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

**Hi guys, I'm trying to display my dictionary map like so:**

```
"black": { 
      "XS": 1, 
      "M": 1, 
      "L": 1, 
      "XL": 2 
    }, 
    "white": { 
      "XS": 1, 
      "L": 1 
    }, 
    "red": { 
      "M": 1 
    }, 
    "blue": { 
      "2XL": 3, 
      "S": 1 
    }
```

**the data given was written like this:**

```
  const products = [
  "black-XS", 
  "black-M", 
  "black-L", 
  "black-XL", 
  "black-XL", 
  "white-XS", 
  "white-L", 
  "red-M", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-S"]
```

**and I wrote this code:**

```
  let Black = new Map();
  let blackSize = new Map();
  blackSize["XS"] = 1;
  blackSize["M"] = 1;
  blackSize["L"] = 1;
  blackSize["XL"] = 2;
  Black["black"] = blackSize;
  console.log(Black);

  let White = new Map();
  let whiteSize = new Map();
  whiteSize["XS"] = 1;
  whiteSize["L"] = 1;
  White["white"] = whiteSize;
  console.log(White);

  let Red = new Map();
  let redSize = new Map();
  redSize["M"] = 1;
  Red["red"] = redSize;
  console.log(Red);

  let Blue = new Map();
  let blueSize = new Map();
  blueSize["2XL"] = 3;
  blueSize["S"] = 1;
  Blue["blue"] = blueSize;
  console.log(Blue);
```

**but that returns:**

```
console.log
    Map { blue: Map { XS: 1, M: 1, L: 1, XL: 2 } }

      
  console.log
    Map { white: Map { XS: 1, L: 1 } }

      
  console.log
    Map { red: Map { M: 1 } }

      
  console.log
    Map { blue: Map { 2XL: 3, S: 1 } }
```

**I'm still a newbie in programming, so I've been trying to figure it out how to use *.forEach* or *for ... in ...* so I don't even need to rewrite the data given and extract directly from it, but I've been failing at it. So I tried to use *map* as a way to display the info, but I'm still not getting to the final answer. Can you guys give me some light?**

## EDIT

**The answer from @Alexey is the better one, more generic and can be applied to any generic shopping item, but I also managed to rearrange my original code like this, using @geofh tip:**

```
  let Shirts = {};
  let blackSize = {};
  blackSize["XS"] = 1;
  blackSize["M"] = 1;
  blackSize["L"] = 1;
  blackSize["XL"] = 2;
  Shirts["black"] = blackSize;
  
  let whiteSize = {};
  whiteSize["XS"] = 1;
  whiteSize["L"] = 1;
  Shirts["white"] = whiteSize;
  
  let redSize = {};
  redSize["M"] = 1;
  Shirts["red"] = redSize;
  
  let blueSize = {};
  blueSize["2XL"] = 3;
  blueSize["S"] = 1;
  Shirts["blue"] = blueSize;

  return(Shirts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intended result looks like `object`, so the next code will convert your products array to that object.

```
const products = [
  "black-XS", 
  "black-M", 
  "black-L", 
  "black-XL", 
  "black-XL", 
  "white-XS", 
  "white-L", 
  "red-M", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-2XL", 
  "blue-S"
];

const result = {};                           // we define new empty object

products.forEach((product)=>{                // let's run through product array
  const props = product.split('-');          // convert black-XS to array ['black', 'XS']
  const [color, size] = props;               // destruct recieved array to variables
  
  if (typeof result[color] !== 'object')
    result[color] = {}                       // create new object for color if it doesn't exists
    
  if (result[color].hasOwnProperty(size)) {
    result[color][size] += 1;                // increment size by one if it is already exists
  } else {
    result[color][size] = 1;                 // set count of new size to 1
  }
});

// write out the result
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)+'</pre>');
```

Feel free to play with it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alimamed/etohrsk5/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for including comments next to the lines, I managed to do it (and understand what I was doing) with this code!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace each occurrence of `new Map()` with `{}`. That will get you much closer I think!

Hard to apply .forEach here, since the numbers you want in your output are not expressed in the input ... so you are hard-coding it. If you reformulate the input to include those numbers, there might exist a more generic solution.

Comment: Your tip was very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the strings and build a nested object stricture with the given keys. Finally increment the last node.

```js
const
    products = ["black-XS", "black-M", "black-L", "black-XL", "black-XL", "white-XS", "white-L", "red-M", "blue-2XL", "blue-2XL", "blue-2XL", "blue-S"],
    result = products.reduce((r, s) => {
        const
            keys = s.split('-'),
            last = keys.pop(),
            target = keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, r);

        target[last] = (target[last] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```